# How do I close connections in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, connection

What exactly does this means:

```
mysql> show status like "Conn%";
```

```
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                     | Value |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Connection_errors_accept          | 0     |
| Connection_errors_internal        | 0     |
| Connection_errors_max_connections | 0     |
| Connection_errors_peer_address    | 0     |
| Connection_errors_select          | 0     |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap         | 0     |
| Connections                       | 16    | <-- This value
+-----------------------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is this a count of how many times I've connected, or a count of how many open connections exist?

Assuming it's the number of open connections, how do I close them?

Comment: it would be useful to indicate the version of MySQL you are using - additionally, since you are new to MySQL I would recommend that one of the first things you do is become familiar with navigating the documentation - and in fact, a quick search through the documentation very quickly and neatly answers your question -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm dumb. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html

Okay, thanks to fqdn for the link to the answer. Connections is just a historical count of past connection attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Connections usually closed by those who opened them so in general case you as DBA shouldn't close them.
Moreover, in most of cases - if client application crashes - Server will be notified about that (tcp protocol usually takes care about that) and connection will be closed automatically
But in some cases Server is not notified about the fact that client went down (e.g. whole client machine crashed or some router in the middle goes down). If those connections are not notified by TCP (timeout or keepalive) - then MySQL server will close them after wait_timeout.
If DBA still wants to force close some connection (e.g. if it suspects some malicious activity or connection stuck or eats too many resources) - they may use SQL command KILL followed by process_id from output of SHOW PROCESSLIST

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful information for the future. I assume you mean write_timeout?